# Not able to run webdriver scripts from jmeter

Tags: testing, load, webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to execute webdriver script from jmeter.
I have installed webdriver plugin.
Created firefox config element and web driver sampler.

Added script under webdriver sampler -

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

But while executing, browser is not opening.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty much sure that you have Firefox version which is not supported by underlying Selenium libraries.

- WebDriver Sampler plugin 1.2.1 supports Firefox 33
- WebDriver Sampler plugin 1.2.0 supports Firefox 26

If you need the latest Firefox for any other reason you can have Firefox 26 or 33 installed somewhere else. Just add the following line to *system.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
webdriver.firefox.bin=/path/to/your/firefox/directory
```

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](http://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more WebDriver sampler tips and tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter only supports some of the versions of Firefox to run Jmeter-webdriver script. Use firefox 45.0 it will work like pro.
The Installation of firefox should be in the default directory, do not custome the path of Firefox 45.0.